# Trying to add a line break after html elements getting add from javascript code inside a display flex div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a line break after HTML elements get added from a javascript after clicking a button.

Here is an example of the issue, the data from the inputs after I click a second time on the submit button, it's just getting placed in the same spot:

[image: Here a image, after i click 2 times submiting the data]

Here is an image of what I wish to happen
[image: What i wish it do]

Here is the function code that running after button is clicked:

```
    function addData() {
    // save the values from the inputs
    // display the calculation and the values on the screen and save it as a local storage
    let strategyValue, sharesValue, enterPriceValue, stopLossValue, profitPriceValue, stockNameValue;

    // creating html nodes
    let breakLine = document.createElement("br");
    let stockStrategy = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockValue = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockPrice = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockStopLoss = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockProfitPrice = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockName = document.createElement("h2");


    // trying to append the html nodes inside the div-result in the DOM in order to display flex the html nodes
    
    

    // saveing the values into variblies
    strategyValue = inputStrategy.value;
    sharesValue = inputShares.value;
    enterPriceValue = inputEnterPrice.value;
    stopLossValue = inputStopLoss.value;
    profitPriceValue = inputProfitPrice.value;
    stockNameValue = inputStockName.value;

    // append value to the html node 
    stockStrategy.innerHTML = strategyValue;
    stockValue.innerHTML = sharesValue;
    stockPrice.innerHTML = enterPriceValue;
    stockStopLoss.innerHTML = stopLossValue;
    stockProfitPrice.innerHTML = profitPriceValue;
    stockName.innerHTML = stockNameValue;

    // i want to add the stockTitle append it to the div-result in the html node

    document.body.appendChild(stockName);
    document.body.appendChild(stockStrategy);
    document.body.appendChild(stockValue);
    document.body.appendChild(stockPrice);
    document.body.appendChild(stockStopLoss);
    document.body.appendChild(stockProfitPrice);
    


    divResult.appendChild(stockStrategy);
    divResult.appendChild(stockValue);
    divResult.appendChild(stockPrice);
    divResult.appendChild(stockStopLoss);
    divResult.appendChild(stockProfitPrice);
    divResult.appendChild(stockName);
    
}
```

Here is the CSS Code:

```
    .div-result {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border: solid 5px blue;
}

.div-result h2{
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
    <body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Power Tracker</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="div-main-inputs">
        <div class="div-inputs">
            <label>Stock Name</label>
            <input value="" type="text" class="input-stock">
            <label>Choice Strategy</label>
            <input value="" type="text" class="input-strategy">
            
            
        </div>

        <div class="div-secondInputs">
            <label>Bought Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-enter">
            <label>Stop Loss Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-stop-loss">
            <label>Profit Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-profit-price">
            <label>Choice Shares</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-shares">
        </div>

        <button class="btn-submit">Submit</button>

    </div>
    <div class="div-result">


    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks for the Helpers.

Comment: where and how is `addData` called?Also, it is not clear by the images what you expect to happen - should there only be a single instance of the portion of elements depicted in blue(ie(swing,500,20...etc) or should there be multiple but on separate lines??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a lot you seem to not understand. If you have specific questions about the answer please ask them.  But first review the solution.

```js
function addData() {

    // save the values from the inputs
    // display the calculation and the values on the screen and save it as a local storage
    let strategyValue, sharesValue, enterPriceValue, stopLossValue, profitPriceValue, stockNameValue;

    // creating html nodes
    let breakLine = document.createElement("br");
    let stockStrategy = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockValue = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockPrice = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockStopLoss = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockProfitPrice = document.createElement("h2");
    let stockName = document.createElement("h2");


    // trying to append the html nodes inside the div-result in the DOM in order to display flex the html nodes
    
    
    

    // saveing the values into variblies
    strategyValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;
    sharesValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;
    enterPriceValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;
    stopLossValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;
    profitPriceValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;
    stockNameValue = document.getElementById('strategy').value;

    // append value to the html node 
    stockStrategy.innerHTML = strategyValue;
    stockValue.innerHTML = sharesValue;
    stockPrice.innerHTML = enterPriceValue;
    stockStopLoss.innerHTML = stopLossValue;
    stockProfitPrice.innerHTML = profitPriceValue;
    stockName.innerHTML = stockNameValue;

    // i want to add the stockTitle append it to the div-result in the html node
    
    divResult = document.getElementById('divResult');
    
    let div = document.createElement("div");

    div.className='div-result'

    div.appendChild(stockName);
    div.appendChild(stockStrategy);
    div.appendChild(stockValue);
    div.appendChild(stockPrice);
    div.appendChild(stockStopLoss);
    div.appendChild(stockProfitPrice);
    div.appendChild(breakLine);
   
   divResult.append(div)
    
}
```

```css
.div-result {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
    ;
}

.div-result h2{
    color: blue;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.div-result0{
border:solid 3px blue;}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Power Tracker</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="div-main-inputs">
        <div class="div-inputs">
            <label>Stock Name</label>
            <input value="" type="text" class="input-stock" id='stockName'>
            <label>Choice Strategy</label>
            <input value="" type="text" class="input-strategy" id = 'strategy'>
            
            
        </div>

        <div class="div-secondInputs">
            <label>Bought Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-enter" id = 'enterPrice'>
            <label>Stop Loss Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-stop-loss" id='stopLoss'>
            <label>Profit Price</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-profit-price" id = 'profitPrice'>
            <label>Choice Shares</label>
            <input value="" type="number" class="input-shares" id='inputShares'>
        </div>

        <button class="btn-submit" onclick="addData()" >Submit</button>

    </div>
    <div class="div-result0" id='divResult'>


    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, just have a question why did you name the div class name to "div-result0" ? and in the javascript, you set the className to "div-result" why without the 0?

Comment: .div-result0 is for the original div in your html.  It's around that we add a blue border.  .div-result is for the divs you are going to append to your html